# Is it possible to set the tick interval's pixel width?

Tags: highcharts, react-highcharts

So I'm basically trying to line up a highcharts chart exactly with an html table that's being rendered just above it.  I'm just wondering if there's any way to have an absolute spacing in pixels between each xAxis tick?

The table's cells have a fixed width and I'm rendering the same data in both.  So far it lines up pretty close, but I'm thinking if I can't fix the spacing of the points, it may be impossible to line up properly.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to use **tickPixelInterval** feature?

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/hauco6s0/

```
Highcharts.chart('container', {
    xAxis: {
        tickPixelInterval: 20
    },

    series: [{
        data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4]
    }]
});
```

API: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/xAxis.tickPixelInterval

If this wouldn't help - please reproduce your case on some online editor which I could work on.